# Get latest persisted id and return it

Tags: java, jpa

I'm using JPA and i want to get he newly persisted id but i don't know how to get it. I'm able to get the id but i don't and display it but i don't know how to get it's value.

I have this method for persisting:

```
    public Artist createArtist(int id, String name, int genre) {
        Artist artist = new Artist(id, name, genre);
        em.persist(artist);
        em.flush();

        System.out.println("Last ID: "+artist.getId()); 
        return artist;
    }
```

and this few lines of code for calling the method:

```
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("JpaBasicsTutorial");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        ArtistService service = new ArtistService(em);
        Artist artista = new Artist();

        EntityTransaction transaction = em.getTransaction();
        transaction.begin();

        Artist artist = service.createArtist(artista.getId(),"Franz", 1); 
        System.out.println("Latest id: " +artista.getId()); // HOW TO GET ID HERE?

        transaction.commit();
        System.out.println(String.format("Persisted: %s\n", artist));
```

here is the code for generating id:

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    public Artist(int id, String name, int genre) {
        this.name = name;
        this.genre = genre;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
```

Comment: Kindly show the code for your Artist entity. It seems like you don't use id generation strategies for your entity and you manually set it.

Comment: Do you want the highest ID number?  Or the last record accessed or updated?

Comment: i actually found out how to get the latest id by displaying it as you can see in the above code but i don't know how to return it.

Comment: @markspace I want the id of the newly inserted data.

Comment: From your code, you are using auto generation for your id field. Right after your persist the entity, you should be able to get the id. What does it print when you call getId()? Do you get any error?

Comment: In the createArtist method i am able to print the latest id but after calling the createArtist method i cannot display it in there it displays '0'

Comment: If you want to fetch an auto-generated row identifier within the current transaction in progress as you stated, then just do `EntityManager#flush();` right before fetching the auto-generated identifier (Caveat : It will introduce an additional round trip to the underlying database).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 objects here - artista and artist. artist was the one that got persisted. artista object was not persisted, so you won't be able to get its ID.

You might want to change this line:

```
System.out.println("Latest id: " +artista.getId());
```

To this:

```
System.out.println("Latest id: " +artist.getId());
```

Also, when instantiating the Artist object, you need not assign its ID, since according to your mapping this is automatically generated.

So this code is possible even without assigning an ID.

```
Artist artist = new Artist();
artist.setName(name);
artist.setGenre(genre);
em.persist(artist);
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what i've been looking for. :)